# Windows 8 ask for repair when launched from grub

Tags: windows, dual-boot, uefi

I've installed Linux Mint and everything works beautifully. After installing I've used boot-repair to be able to launch windows 8 from grub (as I've read somewhere), after that I have those windows-related options in grub:

1. Windows 8 UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi
2. Windows Boot UEFI loader
3. Windows Recovery Environment (loader)
4. Windows 8 (loader)

when I choose option:

1. I get a windows 8 screen "something went wrong..." and the computer restarts and grub is launched again
2. Preperation of Automatic Repair starts, which scared me so I aborted it (I am worried it would mess my linux partition)
3. I didn't try that (again - is that "linux safe"?)
4. A message is displayed:

   error: can't find command `drivemap'.
   error: invalid EFI file path.
   Press any key to continue.

Maybe number 2 would solve my problem I am just scare to run not to mess up my Linux.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221311/grub-errors-during-uefi-dual-boot-for-windows-8-cant-find-command-drivemap (the wiki link in the answer has changed, it's now https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2#Microsoft_Windows_installed_in_UEFI-GPT_mode).

Comment: Note the "drivemap" error is a GRUB error.  It's due to a bug where your grub.cfg is created with grub-pc (BIOS) commands, when it should only have grub-efi commands.  It's a pity boot-repair didn't work for you - it seems to have helped other people with the same problem.

Comment: thx @sourcejedi the first command in the tutorial gives me troubles already. the grub-probe says `cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1.  Check your device.map.` I am looking into it..

Comment: I am an idiot, I forgot I have to use sudo. Anyway I did all of that, but unfortunately that doesnt work. The new item shows up in GRUB but when selected it turns black and then goes to the grub again. No message nothing, just back to grub :(

Comment: 3 hours later I came to a conclusion my Windows partition is broken. When installing Mint I resized the windows partitioned and I think that's what caused those problems. Do you think the windows repair thing will delete my linux partition or I should give it a go?

Answer (score 1):

I came to conclusion I am experiencing those troubles because I resized the windows partition during installation.

I finally tried out the second option in the menu. The Automatic Repair fixed my windows partition, but left the grub and the linux mint intact. I was able to load to windows after that. So to sum it up: just use boot-repair to fix your grub. Then choose UEFI loader and dont get scared by the Automatic Repair (its always a good thing to backup your files though).